# Origin of "you lot" and other plural forms of "you"

Tags: etymology, british-english, linguistics

I've often heard the phrase "you lot" in British programs on PBS, e.g. "[Oi!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oi_%28interjection%29) You lot! Shift y'selves" or thereabouts, and have sometimes wondered about its origin and how it gained currency.  It seems both elegant (short, easily understood, and accurately expressing plural of "you") and crude (on PBS, only heard in broad comedy) or perhaps [colloquial](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/help/british/sb-l.html#lot).  Its use seems to have [sharply increased ca. 1960](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=you%20lot&year_start=1924&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3).

Why the increase, or is it an artifact of the corpus?

Are "you lot", "you-all" and "you guys" (as mentioned in the middle of [Wikipedia on "you"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You)) [cognates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate)? Is there a more appropriate term for the group?

Comment: Just FYI -- it's not really "you all";  the typical usage is "y'all".  The contraction may not be well reflected in literature, but that's the way it's said, and that's the way it's understood.

Comment: @Kyle, as Wikipedia notes, "you-all" is said like that in some instances (I particularly notice it in questions, like *are you-all going?* or *is that you-all's website?*) in the southern USA and in AAVE, but I think you're right that it may not occur in BrE, which is what jwpat7 is primarily interested in :)

Comment: @aedia:  "You-all" is typically used as an intensifier, or when one is slowing things down for those unaccustomed to the use of "y'all".  But this isn't an objection, just a friendly observation.

Comment: @Kyle Pearson is correct regarding American usage. I can vouch for this as a strident American English speaker who probably has no business answering British English questions. Y'all is the correct way to say it. "You all" is closer to more formal usage, at which point one sounds pretentious AND incorrect. Often, I catch myself saying or writing "you all" as an attempt to not say "y'all". But Wikipedia isn't always correct, and that isn't your fault!

Comment: Here I was all this time thinking it was Australian in origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your second question is ‘no’: they are not cognates. Cognates are words descended from a common etymon; that is not a correct description of *you lot*, *you all*, *y'all*, *yeuns*, *you guys*, *you folks*, etc. (except for *you all* and *y’all*, of course). They are phrasal extensions of the bare pronoun *you* created to make it explicitly and unambiguously plural. For some speakers they’ve been fully grammaticalized, meaning that they’re no longer perceived as phrases but are single lexical items. This is especially true of *y'all* and *yeuns* for speakers of the varieties that have these two pronouns. My impression is that some British speakers have lexicalized *you lot*; I’ve encountered Americans who definitely seem to have lexicalized *you guys* (typically as *y(ə)’guys*), though I’ve not been in a position to investigate this scientifically.

Comment: In your list of "explicitly pluralised" forms of *you*, you could include (primarily Northern) British **yous**. For some reason I can't fathom, there seems to be a tendency to spell it **youse** when the writer is trying to draw attention to the fact that he's reporting dialectal/uneducated speech. Maybe it's just that *youse* can also be used for the ungrammatical *"You is"*, which I normally associate with stereotypical portrayal of poorly-educated black Americans in the past (esp. negro slaves on plantations).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks; I’d forgotten about that one. There’s also *yous(e) guys*, found in New York, Philadelphia, and a few other places.

Comment: @Fumble: I think the Irish *yez* is the origin of that one, via Liverpool.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have first hand familiarity with British English. However, there are sufficient counterparts with American usage, particularly in the links provided for clarification, that I'll try to respond.

1. "You" is both the singular and plural form of the word. "You lot" or "You all" seem neither elegant nor accurate, as the plural form of "you" remains "you". "You lot" and "you all" are redundant. I wouldn't even consider them colloquial usage. Slang is more descriptive.
2. Regarding the increase in usage over time: Yes, it did accelerate sharply from 1960 onward. Note though that the trend has reversed. The expression may not have entered the corpus, as usage rates dropped and have returned to levels observed (via your helpful link) last seen in the early 1980's.
3. Cognates: No, they are not.

Comment: Re (1): You’d simply be wrong: far from being slang, *you all* (usually as *y’all*) is fully grammatical and normal in many US spoken varieties. *Yeuns* (more or less) has the same status in some other varieties. Moreover, the explicitly plural forms have arisen precisely because in many contexts they are not pragmatically redundant: speakers find that they need an unambiguously plural second person pronoun. Re (3): They certainly are **not** cognates: they do not have a common etymological origin.

Comment: @jwpat7 No disrespect is intended in my answer, okay? It sounds irritable. I'm not ridiculing you or your question.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Point taken. Edit in progress. They aren't cognates, even slang cognates. I read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%27all see toward end re common etymology i.e. cognates, for youse and yeuse and y'uns, but that applies to American English, and I'm not so certain now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

***Another example of usage***

"**You lot**" is not the only possible usage. Consider this example:

> Well, I just thought... maybe... it was something to do with... you know... **her lot**.

(From JK Rowling's *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*)

In the U.S. edition of the same book, the expression "her lot" was replaced with **"her crowd"**. Apparently, the editor did not consider this usage intuitive enough for a U.S. speaker of English.

***Possible origin***

In my opinion, "you lot" might have evolved from the original meaning of the word 'lot'. I cite dictionary entries below to show how the meaning of this word is extended in British English.

From [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/lot_7):

> **lot** *plural, noun, UK, informal*:  a group of people.
>
> *You're an ignorant lot!
>
>   Are you lot coming to lunch?
>
>   My lot (= children and family generally) won't eat spinach.*
>
> **the lot** *UK, informal*: everything.
>
> *I made enough curry for three people and he ate the lot.
>
>   Have I got everything? Is that the lot?
>
>   I'll sell you the whole lot for only £50.
>
>   I'm sick of the lot of them.*

From the [Oxford Online Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lot?rskey=xLCgjH&result=3):

> **lot** *noun [with adjective] chiefly British*:
>   a group of a specified kind (used in a derogatory or dismissive way):
>   *an inefficient lot, our Council.*

From [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/LOT):

> *informal* **a** *[count] chiefly Brit* : all the members of a group of people — usually singular.
>
> *Do you know **the lot** [=bunch, crowd] that hang around the arcade?
>
>   **That lot** will never amount to anything! They're a thoroughly **bad lot**.
>
>   Pipe down, **the (whole) lot of you**. = Pipe down, **you lot**.*
>
> In British English, a person who is not liked is sometimes described as a bad lot.
>   *He may be a bit wild, but he's not a **bad lot** once you get to know him.*